# How to set up .htaccess for multilanguage website?

Tags: php, .htaccess

I need to set up .htaccess, but it's kinda hard for me to understand anything regarding .htaccess code.

I have set up .htaccess for single language (Croatian), but now I have to add another language (English) that is in folder "en". So, folder structure is like this:

```
/

/index.php
/items.php
/item.php
/contact.php
/404.php

/en/index.php
/en/items.php
/en/item.php
/en/contact.php
/en/404.php
```

With my current .htaccess, Croatian language works just fine, while on English language only index.php works, while other pages open 404.php.
This is my current .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine on

# Remove .php extension ???
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/$ $1.php

# Don't know what this does, would say that removes .php extenstion, too ???
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]+\ /([^/]+/)*[^.]+\.php(\?[^\ ]*)?\ HTTP/
RewriteRule ^(([^/]+/)*[^.]+)\.php$ http://localhost/website/$1 [R=301,L]

# Add trailing "/"
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,5}|/)$
RewriteRule (.*)$ http://localhost/website/$1/ [R=301,L]

# Pretty URLS
RewriteRule ^items/offer/(place_1|place_2)/?$ items.php?place=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^items/offer/(place_1|place_2)/(sale_type_1|sale_type_2)/?$ items.php?place=$1&sale_type=$2 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^items/offer/(place_1|place_2)/(sale_type_1|sale_type_2)/(type_1|type_2|type_3)/?$ items.php?place=$1&sale_type=$2&type=$3 [L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^items/premium/(place_1)/(quart_1|quart_2|quart_3)/?$ items.php?premium=true&place=$1&quart=$2 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^items/premium/(place_1)/(sale_type_1|sale_type_2)/(quart_1|quart_2|quart_3)/?$ items.php?premium=true?place=$1&sale_type=$2&quart=$3 [L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^items/featured/?$ items.php?featured=true [L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^item/([0-9]+)/?$ item.php?id=$1 [L,QSA]

# Errors
ErrorDocument 404 http://localhost/website/404.php
```

Current URLs look like this:

```
/ or /index.php - http://localhost/website/
/items.php - http://localhost/website/items/
/items.php?place=place_1 - http://localhost/website/items/offer/place_1/
/items.php?place=place_1&sale_type=sale_type_2 - http://localhost/website/items/offer/place_1/sale_type_2/
/items.php?place=place_1&sale_type=sale_type_2&type=type_3 - http://localhost/website/items/offer/place_1/sale_type_2/type_3/
/items.php?premium=true&place=place_1&quart=quart_2 - http://localhost/website/items/premium/place_1/quart_2/
/items.php?premium=true&place=place_1&sale_type=sale_type_2&quart=quart_3 - http://localhost/website/items/premium/place_1/sale_type_2/quart_3/
/items.php?featured=true - http://localhost/website/items/featured/
/item.php?id=4269 - http://localhost/website/item/4269/
/contact.php - http://localhost/website/contact/
/404.php - http://localhost/website/404/
```

How can I make same thing, but with en folder? And, am I doing something wrong? Any tutorial regarding .htaccess code for multiple languages with default language files in root, and other languages in separate folders, would be helpfull.